# What is K Max Pooling? How to implement it in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, max-pooling

I have to add a k-max pooling layer in CNN model to detect fake reviews. Please can you let me know how to implement it using keras.

I searched the internet but I got no good resources.

Answer (score 5):

As per this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2188.pdf), k-Max Pooling is a pooling operation that is a generalisation of the max pooling over the time dimension used in the Max-TDNN sentence model
and different from the local max pooling operations applied in a convolutional network for object recognition (LeCun et al., 1998).

[image]

The k-max pooling operation makes it possible
to pool the k most active features in p that may be
a number of positions apart; it preserves the order
of the features, but is insensitive to their specific
positions.

There are few resources which show how to implement it in tensorflow or keras:

- [How to implement K-Max pooling in Tensorflow or Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299181/how-to-implement-k-max-pooling-in-tensorflow-or-keras)
- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/373
- [New Pooling Layers For Varying-Length Convolutional Networks](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~yjzhang/notebooks/2016/2016-3-10%20-%20New%20Pooling%20Layers.html)

Answer (score 2):

## Keras implementation of K-Max Pooling with TensorFlow Backend

There seems to be a solution [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/373#issuecomment-319890866) as @Anubhav_Singh suggested. This response got almost 5 times more thumbs up (24) than thumbs down (5) on the github keras issues link. I am just quoting it `as-is` here and let people try it out and say whether it worked for them or not.

Original author: [arbackus](https://github.com/arbackus)

```py
from keras.engine import Layer, InputSpec
from keras.layers import Flatten
import tensorflow as tf

class KMaxPooling(Layer):
    """
    K-max pooling layer that extracts the k-highest activations from a sequence (2nd dimension).
    TensorFlow backend.
    """
    def __init__(self, k=1, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=3)
        self.k = k

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], (input_shape[2] * self.k))

    def call(self, inputs):

        # swap last two dimensions since top_k will be applied along the last dimension
        shifted_input = tf.transpose(inputs, [0, 2, 1])

        # extract top_k, returns two tensors [values, indices]
        top_k = tf.nn.top_k(shifted_input, k=self.k, sorted=True, name=None)[0]

        # return flattened output
        return Flatten()(top_k)
```

Note: it was reported to be running very slow (though it worked for people).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Not thoroughly tested but works fine for me. Let me know what you think. P.S. Latest tensorflow version.

tf.nn.top_k does not preserve the order of occurrence of values. So, that is the think that need to be worked upon

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
class KMaxPooling(layers.Layer):
    """
    K-max pooling layer that extracts the k-highest activations from a sequence (2nd dimension).
    TensorFlow backend.
    """
    def __init__(self, k=1, axis=1, **kwargs):
        super(KMaxPooling, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.input_spec = layers.InputSpec(ndim=3)
        self.k = k

        assert axis in [1,2],  'expected dimensions (samples, filters, convolved_values),\
                   cannot fold along samples dimension or axis not in list [1,2]'
        self.axis = axis

        # need to switch the axis with the last elemnet
        # to perform transpose for tok k elements since top_k works in last axis
        self.transpose_perm = [0,1,2] #default
        self.transpose_perm[self.axis] = 2
        self.transpose_perm[2] = self.axis

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        input_shape_list = list(input_shape)
        input_shape_list[self.axis] = self.k
        return tuple(input_shape_list)

    def call(self, x):
        # swap sequence dimension to get top k elements along axis=1
        transposed_for_topk = tf.transpose(x, perm=self.transpose_perm)

        # extract top_k, returns two tensors [values, indices]
        top_k_vals, top_k_indices = tf.math.top_k(transposed_for_topk,
                                                  k=self.k, sorted=True,
                                                  name=None)
        # maintain the order of values as in the paper
        # sort indices
        sorted_top_k_ind = tf.sort(top_k_indices)
        flatten_seq = tf.reshape(transposed_for_topk, (-1,))
        shape_seq = tf.shape(transposed_for_topk)
        len_seq = tf.shape(flatten_seq)[0]
        indices_seq = tf.range(len_seq)
        indices_seq = tf.reshape(indices_seq, shape_seq)
        indices_gather = tf.gather(indices_seq, 0, axis=-1)
        indices_sum = tf.expand_dims(indices_gather, axis=-1)
        sorted_top_k_ind += indices_sum
        k_max_out = tf.gather(flatten_seq, sorted_top_k_ind)
        # return back to normal dimension but now sequence dimension has only k elements
        # performing another transpose will get the tensor back to its original shape
        # but will have k as its axis_1 size
        transposed_back = tf.transpose(k_max_out, perm=self.transpose_perm)

        return transposed_back
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of k-max pooling as explained in the comment of @Anubhav Singh above (the order of topk is preserved)

```
def test60_simple_test(a):
# swap last two dimensions since top_k will be applied along the last dimension
    #shifted_input = tf.transpose(a) #[0, 2, 1]

    # extract top_k, returns two tensors [values, indices]
    res = tf.nn.top_k(a, k=3, sorted=True, name=None)
    b = tf.sort(res[1],axis=0,direction='ASCENDING',name=None)
    e=tf.gather(a,b)
    #e=e[0:3]
    return (e)

a = tf.constant([7, 2, 3, 9, 5], dtype = tf.float64) 
print('*input:',a)
print('**output', test60_simple_test(a))
```

The result:

```
*input: tf.Tensor([7. 2. 3. 9. 5.], shape=(5,), dtype=float64)
**output tf.Tensor([7. 9. 5.], shape=(3,), dtype=float64)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a `Pytorch` version implementation of k-max pooling:

```
import torch
def kmax_pooling(x, dim, k):
    index = x.topk(k, dim = dim)[1].sort(dim = dim)[0]
    return x.gather(dim, index)
```

Hope it would help.